# posting javascript variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am trying to post a javascript variable to PHP so that I can update the database on my localhost. The PHP seems to connect to the database but the database is not being updated.

```
<?php

include "main.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- START OF GEOLOCATION -->


<center><div class="round-button"><div class="round-button-circle"><a onclick= "getLocation()" class="round-button">HELP</a></div></div></center>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>




<script>

var glob_latitude = '';
var glob_longitude = '';

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }


///send to ip
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;



       glob_longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        glob_latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    $.post( "main.php", { latitude: glob_latitude, longitude: glob_longitude } postPosition(position); 

}

function postPosition(position){
    $.post('main.php',{
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
    },function(phpScriptResponse){
        if(phpScriptResponse !== "ok"){ x.innerHTML= phpScriptResponse; }
      }
    }
  );
}

    </script>


      </body>
    </html>
```

here is the PHP code that's supposed to update the database after connecting  ...

```
<?php


$dbConnection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root" , "" ,"info");

if($dbConnection)
    {
        echo "connected"; 
        if(isset($_POST['latitude']) and isset($_POST['longitude'])){
            echo "hi";
            $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
            $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

            if($latitude != '' and $longitude != '')
                echo "hi";
                $query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO info VALUES (NULL, '{$latitude}', '$longitude')");

        }

    }
else
    die();

mysqli_close($dbConnection);
?>
```

Comment: You code is missing a ``form``. You are trying to retrieve ``$_POST['latitude']`` but you never post it.

Comment: Which variables do you want to send to PHP `glob_longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    glob_latitude = position.coords.latitude;
`

Comment: I added 



$.post( "main.php", { latitude: glob_latitude, longitude: glob_longitude } );


but still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Where do you post the data to your PHP? All I see us a '<a onclick= "getLocation()"', and in the function you get the position, but you stop there.
Your function need to call your PHP script about the data change:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        return ;
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

    var data = {
        'longitude': position.coords.longitude,
        'latitude': position.coords.latitude
    } ;

    // now tell PHP via Ajax
    $.post ('myphp.php', data, function (ret, status) { alert (ret) ; }) ;
}
```

And because I send a json object, you may need to adapt the PHP script a bit.

Comment: I have made the suggestion you mentioned but for some reason now it doesn't even get the gps location at all

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, is the getLocation() and showPosition() functions not called? which means you changed something to make it stop working - checkout the javascript console in case there is an error. Or did you meant you stopped receiving the gps information from your device? again the javascript console may help to find what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
var glob_latitude = '';
var glob_longitude = '';

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }


///send to ip
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

    glob_longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    glob_latitude = position.coords.latitude;

    postPosition(position); 

}

function postPosition(position){
    $.post('url/to/your.php',{
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
    },function(phpScriptResponse){
        if(phpScriptResponse !== "connectedhihi"){
        // error
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I have added the function, yet I don't see the data in the database

Comment: I added 

if(phpScriptResponse !== "connectedhihi"){
        x.innerHTML= "error"
      }    it started showing error

Comment: I would suggest the following: Make sure your PHP script write 'ok' (or what ever) to stdout if there is no error and write the error in case there is one. Then you can change it to `if(phpScriptResponse !== "ok"){ x.innerHTML= phpScriptResponse; }`

Comment: The code somehow doesn't want to go beyond the database connection part, once its connected nothing happens after that

Answer (score 0):

As so far you don't have a form in your  html file you can use `AJAX` to process your data to `PHP`. At this moment don't include `main.php` file

```
            var glob_latitude = '';
        var glob_longitude = '';

        var x = document.getElementById("demo");

        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
            }


        ///send to ip
        function showPosition(position) {
            x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

            glob_longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            glob_latitude = position.coords.latitude;

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "main.php";
        var params = "latitude="+glob_latitude+"&longitude="+glob_longitude+"";
        http.open("POST", url, true);

        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-              urlencoded");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
         if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
             alert(http.responseText);
       }
    }
  http.send(params);

}
```

Comment: Would I need a server for this ? because I am currently trying to get it to work on local host for now

Comment: Yes, you should have the server up and running

Comment: This is how you receive your values in PHP  `$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];`